# How do I use Camomile for UTF8 strings in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml, camomile

I have downloaded [Camomile](http://camomile.sourceforge.net/) and installed it and I am good to go for using it.

The question is how should I use it?

in ocaml, for default string, i just do `let s = "a string";;`

but what with `Camomile`?

for example, if I want to construct a `utf8` string `こんにちは` (a Japanese word for hello, copied from google translate), how should I do it with `Camomile`?

---

**Edit:**

It is funny that it is said that `ocaml` can't support `utf8`, but I tried this code

```
let s = "你好";;

let _ = print_string s;print_string "\n";;
```

it worked in ocaml. But why?? `你好` is a Chinese, how can ocaml can print it and handle it if everyone says `ocaml 4.00.1` cannot handle `utf8`?

Comment: When they say OCaml itself doesn't support UTF-8, they are likely saying that there is no built-in support, such as safely comparing UNICODE characters, sorting, upper/lowercasing, etc. You get UTF-8 in strings largely due to the design of UTF-8 encoding, and not because of OCaml support. UTF-8 was designed to flow through byte oriented text systems that were ignorant of UNICODE and UTF-8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a short presentation of the different actors:

- [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) is both a set of characters (there are 127 of them) and a code to represent them (on 7 bits).
- [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set) is a set of characters (there are a lot more than 127).
- [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a code to represent unicode characters.
- Your terminal. It interprets bytes output by your program as UTF-8 encoded characters and displays the corresponding unicode characters.
- OCaml process sequences of bytes (OCaml uses the name `char` but it is misleading and the name `byte` would be more appropriate).

So if OCaml outputs the sequence of bytes corresponding to the UTF-8 code for `"你好"`, your terminal will interpret it as a utf-8 string and will output `你好`. But for OCaml, `"你好"` is just a sequence of 6 bytes.

Comment: ok, my question is then: when I say `let s = "ab";;`, ocaml will know they are just 2 bytes; when I say `let s = "你好";;`, ocaml will know they are 6 bytes. How ocaml know the difference if ocaml doesn't know the encoding? or another way to ask is that why `let c = '你';;` is not working while `let s = "你";;` is?

Comment: That's because ' is the delimiter for bytes and " for sequences of bytes. In your case, when you enter 你, your terminal translate it to a UTF-8 byte sequence of length > 1.

Comment: so this will happen when I write 你 into a source file, right? and ocaml also get those bytes from the text file, right?

Comment: Exactly, 你 is just a sequence of bytes and the only program that is aware that these 3 bytes represent a single character is your terminal.

Comment: ok, i understand more now. so actually `ocaml string type` can actually accept any utf8 string or even any `utf16` string, although it doesn't understand it, it just considers it as a byte array. If my code doesn't need to transfer between diff encodings, ocaml's string can perfectly do the job, such as storing the string somewhere or transfer the string (byte array) over tcp, etc, as long as the other end know it is utf8 or the encoding, right?

Answer (score 3):

TörökEdwin told you everything you need to know, I think. UTF-8 is specifically designed as a way to store Unicode values (codepoints) in a series of 8-bit bytes when the code is used to dealing with ASCII C strings. Since OCaml strings are a series of 8-bit bytes there's no problem *storing* a UTF-8 value there. If the program you use to create your OCaml source handles UTF-8, then it will have no trouble creating a string containing a UTF-8 value. You don't need to do anything special to get that to happen. (As I said I've done this many times myself.)

If you don't need to process the value, then the OCaml I/O functions can also write out such a value (or read one in), and if the encoding of your display is UTF-8 (which is what I use), it will display correctly. But most often you will need to process your values. If you change your code to (for example) just write out the *length* of the string, you might start to see why you would need a special library for handling UTF-8.

If you wonder why a certain Unicode string is represented as a certain series of bytes in the UTF-8 encoding you just need to read up on UTF-8. The Wikipedia article ([UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)) might be a reasonable place to start.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an UTF8 library only if you want to convert between different encoding, to normalize unicode, or if you want to access individual codepoints.

OCaml treats strings as 8-bit binary values of a specified length, so you can use any encoding directly.
i.e. you can just assign the UTF8 value directly to a variable:

```
# let foo = "こんにちは";;
val foo : string =
  "\227\129\147\227\130\147\227\129\171\227\129\161\227\129\175"
```

Comment: I am writting bson lib in ocaml. what I am really concerned is that if I use `string` directly, I cannot handle the `ename` (key) in bson. should I be concerned? also what is `\227` inside the result? I got confused. Can you explain why "こんにちは" is transferred to `\227\129\147\227\130\147\227\129\171\227\129\161\227\129\175` ?

Comment: @Thomash, sorry you're right. \227 is not in octal, it is in decimal. If I convert "こんにちは" into decimal I get:od -A n -t u1
こんにちは
 227 129 147 227 130 147 227 129 171 227 129 161 227 129 175